# Eclipse shortcut to autofill a usefull type of instance variable?

Tags: java, eclipse

What is the Eclipse shortcut for getting an instance variable in this example?

If I write

```
new String("TestString");
```

now I would like to autofill an Instance type of

```
String s =
```

How can I do this with Eclipse IDE to get this result:

```
String s = new String("TestString");
```

Answer (score 7):

With the cursor at the start of the line Ctrl + 1 should bring up a context menu with the option assign to new local variable, I think that is what you are looking for. P.S new rather than New will compile much better ;-)

Comment: It does nothing for me with default config, it might be the option in Refactor > Extract Local Variable ?

Comment: @NeeL It works for me, with default configuration, so I think you may have misunderstood what jcmwright meant. I could be wrong.

Comment: Ctrl + 1 is a standard eclipse shortcut and should work out of the box without any settings changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own "Templates",

On Eclipse open Window > Java > Editor > Templates, click the button New...

In your name put the thing you want to type to auto-complete, then put the code in pattern.

But if you just need simple auto-completion, in general eclipse does that by default using CTRL+SPACE

If you need to complete your statement you can use SHIFT+ALT+L too (you can find it in Refactor > Extract Local Variable)